# how to enable multicore support in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

We are using Neo4j database with 100000 contacts in the graphDB. When we try to insert or update any node in Neo4jcpu utilization is going to 100% and it is using single core only. Is there a way to use Multicore in Neo4j?

Comment: Hello. You might want to explain through what means you are doing the insert/update (cypher, java code, ...). For example a given cypher statement does currently (Neo is working on that) indeed use a single thread. So what might also be interesting to see is your actual statement to check it for improvements.

Comment: You should also share the relevant constraints and indexes, as attempting to match on an existing node to modify it can be expensive unless you have an index or constraint to speed up the match.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is definitely lack of index, so each update makes a fullscan. This behaviour is common for most (or all) DBMS.

A tricky thing in Neo4j is that it cannot create index on nodes without label. Label your nodes or if your nodes have unique value, you can help with unique constraint

Cypher examples:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (movie:Movie) ASSERT movie.title IS UNIQUE

CREATE INDEX ON :Actor(name)
```

In general, you can dramatically improve insert speed by using **neo4j-import** or **neo4j-admin** (to about 15 million nodes per minute).

[link to documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/get-started/cypher/labels-constraints-and-indexes/)